# How do I uninstall Phalcon?

Tags: php, phalcon

I see there procedure for intalling Phalcon on various systems. I would like to try out Phalcon, but I can't see a way to uninstall it bringing the system back to the way it was before.

I am aiming to try it out without hampering anything ... on my local machine.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, Php 5.5.17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use ubuntu then it's all about editing php.ini and disabling phalcon extension.  Then restarting server to apply new configuration.

[Here](http://codeboxr.com/blogs/how-to-disable-gd-library-for-php-in-ubuntu-12-04) you can find example of removing GD extension from PHP. You can do analogy with phalcon.